# Magento site launch to live server display only home page

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, magento

We are currently hosted on bluehost.

Our old website is on the root folder of public_html. We have develop a new one and place it on a sub-directory folder called prototype. The prototype is now finished and we want our main domain to redirect the new develop website.

> Note: They are both on the live server and we use addon domain to
>   access the prototype.

We have updated our .htaccess to this

```
# BlueHost.com 
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?ourdomain.com$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prototype/ 
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /prototype/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?ourdomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ prototype/index.php [L]
```

> We also updated our url's secure and unsecure including other url. We
>   also clear logs, caches, and sessions.

The problem is that the homepage is working but when we try to navigate on other pages it display the homepage of the **old** website even though the url is correct. Some pages has the correct url but for others like about us and contact us, the url is from the old site. This is kinda weird, instead of showing 404 page the old website homepage is displaying.

We can't even access the magento admin.

I don't have any idea on how to solve this.

Is it something to do with our hosting provider?

Do we need to restart the server?

Comment: Are you deleted your cache folder? first delete it try may it helps you.

Comment: are you got 404 for other pages ?

Comment: @Dinesh Bhojvani yes, I deleted the cache folder.

Comment: @Sunny Rathod its kinda weird but its not 404 instead the old website is showing.

Comment: Please clear cache and your browser cache, Make you sure that in your server not installed mam cache varnish or any other related to this.

Comment: Please clear cache and your browser cache, Make you sure that in your server not installed mam cache varnish or any other related to this.

Comment: I'm using incognito, all cache was cleared and deleted

Answer (score 0):

I think as your magento installation in sub folder.You need to update table
core_config_data table with

```html
web/unsecure/base_url =>  http://your-domain/prototype/ 
web/secure/base_url =>  http://your-domain/prototype/
```

The follow the following step.

1. clear cache.
2. do indexing

I hope it will work for you.